# Closure and imported functions in Powershell

Tags: powershell, closures

I have two PowerShell scripts. `Test-Stuff.ps1` and `Functions.ps1`. `Test-Stuff.ps1` rely on `Functions.ps1`, including a function that surround a function call to `Write-Host` the beginning and the end of the function excecution passed as parameter.

It works fine as long as the function passed as parameter does also not come from `Functions.ps1`. If that's the case the parameters to the passed functions are not captured by the invocation function.

`Test-Stuff.ps1`

```bsh
# Let's stop whenever there is something wrong
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Cleanup screen
Clear-Host

# We import the functions in that other PowerShell files
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\Functions.ps1" -Force

# Works fine
Invoke { Set-Location -Path $PSScriptRoot } "Change Current Working Directory to $PSScriptRoot"

# works fine too
Invoke { Write-Host "Testing" -ForegroundColor Red }

$configurationFileName = "Preprod.json"

# Works just fine
$configuration = Invoke { Get-Content -Raw -Path $configurationFileName | ConvertFrom-Json } "Fetch configuration"

$userName = $configuration.userName
$password = $configuration.serviceAccountPassword

# Does not work
$credential = Invoke { New-Credential $userName $password } "Fetch credential"
```

`Functions.ps1`

```bsh
Function Write-Start($text)
{
    Write-Host ([System.Environment]::NewLine + "${text}...") -ForegroundColor Gray
}

Function Write-Stop($text)
{
    Write-Host ("${text}: Done") -ForegroundColor Green
}

Function Invoke([scriptblock]$scriptBlock, $text)
{
    Write-Start $text
    $result = $scriptBlock.Invoke()
    Write-Stop $text
    return $result
}
```

Execution of `.\TestStuff.ps1`:

```sh
Change Current Working Directory to C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\LetsSortThingsOut\KYC\Manual Deployment...
Change Current Working Directory to C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\LetsSortThingsOut\KYC\Manual Deployment: Done

...
Testing
: Done

Fetch configuration...
Fetch configuration: Done

Fetch credential...
Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s): "Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "userName" is not
valid. Change the value of the "userName" argument and run the operation again.""
At C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\LetsSortThingsOut\KYC\Manual Deployment\Functions.ps1:15 char:5
+     $result = $scriptBlock.Invoke()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletInvocationException

PS C:\Users\eperret\Desktop\LetsSortThingsOut\KYC\Manual Deployment>
```

I tried to leverage `GetNewClosure`

```bsh
$credential = Invoke { New-Credential $userName $password }.GetNewClosure() "Fetch credential"
```

... but does not seem to help much, how can I enforce the capture of the passed function parameters?

Comment: What is value for `$userName`?

Comment: @PetSerAl a string, like my "ehouarn.perret" for example

Comment: What is **exact** value of `$userName` when exception occurs?

Comment: @PetSerAl well it was empty guess we can close the topic, I picked the wrong json property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the contents of your scriptblock `New-Credential $userName $password`.  I am unfamiliar with that cmdlet, is it from a module you have written or imported?  If it is a valid cmdlet, it seems that maybe there is a problem with the contents of the arguments or there isn't an "overload" that matches them.

Maybe you should `.Trim()` and `.ToString()` that `$Configuration.userName`